# laravel subquery select, tables with composite primary key

Tags: sql, laravel, subquery

I am trying to pass an sql query to laravel but in this query the tables are joined using composite primary keys and additionally it has subqueries to these tables so I don't know how to do it

The sql code is as shown below

```
            select distinct g.id,
            (   
                select count(*) from xxx s(nolock) inner join yyy t(nolock) 
                on t.id=s.id 
                and t.year=s.year 
                and t.code=s.code 
                where s.year = 2017 
                and t.status<>'C'
                and s.created_at>=convert(datetime,'16/08/2017 00:00:00',103) 
                and s.created_at<=convert(datetime,'22/08/2017 23:59:59',103) 
                and s.id=g.id
            ) as xxx,
            (
                select count(*) from zzz s(nolock) inner join yyy t(nolock) 
                on t.id=s.id 
                and t.year=s.year 
                and t.code=s.code 
                where s.year = 2017 
                and t.status<>'C'
                and s.created_at>=convert(datetime,'16/08/2017 00:00:00',103) 
                and s.created_at<=convert(datetime,'22/08/2017 23:59:59',103) 
                and s.id=g.id
            ) as zzz
            from globals g(nolock) order by g.id
```

It has many subqueries like these two that I put here, same conditions in the joins and same where clause but different tables, any idea how to do this in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to use raw queries in Laravel.

`DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);`

Read more about this here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#running-queries

Answer (score 0):

Solved :3, I can't believe it was this easy, I tried this and it worked. Thanks for your help and sorry for bothering. :$

```
            $data = \DB::table("globals")
                        ->select("globals.id",
                            \DB::raw("(select count(*) from xxx s(nolock) inner join yyy t(nolock) 
                                    on t.id=s.id 
                                    and t.year=s.year 
                                    and t.code=s.code 
                                    where s.year = 2017 
                                    and t.status<>'C'
                                    and s.created_at>=convert(datetime,'16/08/2017 00:00:00',103) 
                                    and s.created_at<=convert(datetime,'22/08/2017 23:59:59',103) 
                                    and s.id=globals.id
                                ) as xxx
                            "),
                            \DB::raw("(select count(*) from zzz s(nolock) inner join yyy t(nolock) 
                                    on t.id=s.id 
                                    and t.year=s.year 
                                    and t.code=s.code 
                                    where s.year = 2017 
                                    and t.status<>'C'
                                    and s.created_at>=convert(datetime,'16/08/2017 00:00:00',103) 
                                    and s.created_at<=convert(datetime,'22/08/2017 23:59:59',103) 
                                    and s.id=globals.id
                                ) as zzz
                            ")
                        )
                        ->orderBy('globals.id', 'asc')
                        ->get();
```